# Comparing two URLs to see if path traversal is available by reading the content of page in python

Tags: python, security

I am trying to compare two URLs using python. Basically I want to test if directory traversal can be performed or not.
I am trying to compare the content of the page if it redirects to the same page, then it is not vulnerable and if it's different then it's vulnerable.
I have tried the following code. after the input is taken, it shows an error.

Code:

```
import urllib
def pywalker():
    target_url= input("Enter url :")
    res = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+target_url+"../../../etc/password")
    res2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+target_url)
    if res.read() == res2.read():
        print("Same webpage")
    else:
        print("Not same ")
pywalker()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-63-e0e37c2314c8>", line 11, in <module>
    pywalker()

  File "<ipython-input-63-e0e37c2314c8>", line 4, in pywalker
    res = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+target_url+"../../../etc/password")

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1345, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 928, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901399/python-requests-encoding-with-idna-codec-failed-unicodeerror-label-empty-o) says this error happens when the URL is longer than 64 characters. Is that the case here?

Comment: @Barmar yes, as you can see that in my code that res, has long URL, what can be done to solve this?

Comment: I don't know of a solution. In the other question the length was due to putting the authentication credentials in the URL, so it was solved by moving them to a header, but that doesn't help here.

Comment: Actually, the bug report says the problem is with long host names, not the entire URL length. So this seems like a different problem.

Comment: @Barmar i tried shortening the URL length, but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you see my last comment? The length limit is only on the hostname part of the URL. This is a different problem, it has nothing to do with length.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://bugs.python.org/issue782510

Comment: I suggest you google the error message like I did, maybe you'll find something useful in the results.

Comment: Does this happen with any `target_url`, or only specific ones?

Comment: @Barmar its with every url, also i have googled it and didn't find anything relevant to my question. i think there may be any error in the code. is there any other way of comparing two URLs web page content and displaying TRUE if same?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with comparing the contents of web pages. You're getting the error just trying to read the web pages, which is a perfectly normal thing to do with the `urllib` module.

Comment: So either this is a bug in `urllib`, or there's a problem with the URL. Make sure there are no special characters in the URL.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, BTW, I get a different error: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`

Comment: I think that's because my server is configured to block URLs like this. The request doesn't even show up in its access log. I tried with www.google.com and got a 404 error.