# UnicodeError 'idna' encoding when working with Heroku, Redis and Flask

Tags: python, sockets, flask, heroku, redis

I have a Flask REST API hosted on Heroku with a Heroku-Redis server.

When code that tries to access the Redis server is executed I get the following error.

`UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)`

The code that seems to cause this error is,

```
revoked_store.set(access_jti, 'false', ACCESS_EXPIRES * 1.2)
revoked_store.set(refresh_jti, 'false', REFRESH_EXPIRES * 1.2)
```

The connection is set here:

```
revoked_store = redis.StrictRedis(host=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'), port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
```

From looking at various other posts I think this error is caused by the Redis URL being too long (>64 characters). [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901399/python-requests-encoding-with-idna-codec-failed-unicodeerror-label-empty-o)

I am not sure how to fix this effort so any help would be appreciated.

If you require more information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, then [I just read the documentation on Heroku Redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#connecting-in-python).

For reference, I did the following, and it solved my issue:

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import redis

url = urlparse(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
r = redis.Redis(host=url.hostname, port=url.port, username=url.username, password=url.password, ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
```