# (Python) Fill the column by webscraping the data on the website. Getting an error: UnicodeError: label empty or too long

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| ID | Link |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5565558html' |
| 2 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5489292html' |
| 3 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5538258html' |
| 4 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5523020html' |
| 5 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5543794html' |

These links lead to the same website, but different pages of it. It is real estate marketplace website and these links lead to each property page, where there is a description for each property.
What I need to do is to extract the name of the property from these pages, so that in the end it looks like this:

| ID | Link | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5565558html' | The One Townhouses |
| 2 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5489292html' | Twin Villas |
| 3 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5538258html' | City Park |
| 4 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5523020html' | The Sky |
| 5 | 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5543794html' | La Mer |

For this, I tried to webscrape these pages in the following way:

```
links=['https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5565558html', 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5489292html', 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5538258html', 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5523020html', 'https://wwwexamplecom/hello/details-5543794html']

data=[]

for link in links:
  html_text=requests.get(link).content
  soup=BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')
  project=soup.find_all('a',class_='_146bd1c5')
  data.append({
      'link':link,
      'project':project
  })
```

But, got an error: UnicodeError: label empty or too long

How to solve this issue? Or maybe you can recommend other ways to fill 'Name' column, but not web scraping

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901399/python-requests-encoding-with-idna-codec-failed-unicodeerror-label-empty-o

Comment: @3r1c it's different, i am not workinh with API

Comment: ok, i gotcha. try  to add a www after https://

Comment: with a dot of course

Comment: @3r1c thanks, worked (i could not add dot here, because it doesn't read as df, but it worked)